# Изменение элементов массива при наличии в нем определенного символа

Tags: javascript

Приветствую уважаемое сообщество. Есть у меня к примеру массив:

```
var arr = [1, 63, 7, 12, 10, 1, 34, 3, 41, 45, 50, 1, 22, 33];
```

Задача получить массив:

```
var result = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Идея такова, что цикл проходит по каждому элементу. Если он встречает единицу, своеобразный флаг,то он меняет все элементы, включая флаг, от текущего элемента единицы до следующего, на единицу. При встрече еще одной единицы, повторяется все тоже, только уже элементы меняются на двойки и т.д.
Думал сначала превратить массив в строку, и разделить её с помощью split, собрать потом в отдельные массивы и видоизменять каждый массив по раздельности, но split удаляет разделитель, который мне то нужен. Была мысль задействовать map, но в итоге так и не сообразил, как же задать корректно условие.

Comment: Первая единица в исходном массиве всегда присутствует?

Comment: Все именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1, 63, 7, 12, 10, 1, 34, 3, 41, 45, 50, 1, 22, 33];
//var result = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]
var current = 0;
var result = arr.map(el => (el == 1)? ++current : current);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Громадное спасибо. Теперь глядя на ваше решение, чувствую себя полнейшим болваном ибо ничего сложного то в нем нет.